# Laravel migration doesn't work while adding new migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, portfolio, laravel-8

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePortfoliosTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('portfolios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image_1');
            $table->string('image_2');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

   
}
```

I create this migration and then run it
PHP artisan migrate, but it doesn't work.

I'm using the latest version of level 8
What should I do?

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\shahabuddin>php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 


  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\shahabuddin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\shahabuddin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I faced those error

Comment: what "doesn't work" ... what are you expecting to happen, what is actually happening? did you use `artisan make:migration` to create this file?

Comment: this should make a table called portfolios in the db but it doesn't create a table. @lagbox

Comment: what is the filename of this file? did you use `artisan make:migration` to create it?

Comment: I use this command to create that migration php artisan make:model Portfolio -m @lagbox

Comment: Do your migrations have `public function down()` methods? Since you ran `migrate:fresh` (as instructed below), it _should_ have removed all tables from your DB, but only if you have that logic in `down()`. If you don't, then you'll need to delete the tables manually then re-run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: yes, I have the down() method too as I'm new in laravel and trying to work with it.

Comment: Well, it's trying to run the migration `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` again, do you gave `Schema::dropIfExists('users')` in that migration? Cause it looks like it reversed the migrations, but didn't drop that table, and now you can't create the table moving forward as it already exists

Comment: @TimLewis 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php has the Schema::dropIfExists('users'). So what should I do now

Comment: Manually delete your `users` table I guess? I'm not sure how you got into that state... It's trying to run the migration again (since it's missing from your `migrations` table), but it didn't successfully delete it when you run `migrate:fresh`, and I'm not sure why that is.